# Create plugin that works in background

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I want to create a plugin that does some work in the background. I have a user interface in the admin backend where I have some buttons:

- start fetching posts
- stop fetching

When I press *start fetching* the plugin fetches some texts from an external API and creates a WordPress post for each text. But that are about 500.000 texts which have to be fetched. Since WordPress is based on PHP and I am not able to activate ZTS (thread-safety) for PHP on my webserver, each request for each text is made sequentially

1. send request to API
2. process the response
3. create a WordPress post (and maybe category) for the text
4. if there are texts left, goto 1.

So for about 500.000 texts this takes **a lot** of time. I wanted to know if you have an idea or a solution how to make the script faster or maybe how to use multi-threading, even if I don't have the ability to activate ZTS.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [WP Background Processing](https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing) which fire off non-blocking asynchronous requests.

WooCommerce also use this for background processing. Check the file [/includes/libraries/wp-background-process.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/libraries/wp-background-process.php)

Comment: Nice! That looks really great, I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that isn't really what I was looking for. You're right, the requests are made asynchronous, but one after one. What I need is something to make parallel requests.